# How to filter by dates and grouping months together in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe (lets call it df1) that looks something like this...

```
Date          Price
2014-08-06       22
2014-08-06       89
2014-09-15       56
2014-06-04       41
2015-01-19       11
2015-05-23        5
2014-07-21      108
```

There are other variables in the dataframe but we will ignore them for now, as I do not require them.

I have previously ordered it using

```
df2 <- df1[order(as.Date(df1$Date, format="%Y/%m/%d")),]
```

And then created a dataframe containing the values for just one month, for example, just September 2015 dates...

```
september2015 <- df2[df2$Date >= "2015-09-01" & df2$Date <= "2015-09-30",]
```

I have done this for all the months in 2015 and 2014.
Then I need to create an average of prices within each given month. I have done this by...

```
mean(september2015$Price, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Obviously, this is very long and tedious and involves many lines of code. I am trying to make my code more efficient through using the dplyr package.

So far I have...

```
datesandprices <- select(df2, Date, Price)

datesandprices <- arrange(datesandprices, Date)

summarise(datesandprices, avg = mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or in a simpler form...

```
df1 %>%
    select(Date, Price) %>%
    arrange(Date) %>%
    filter(Date >= 2014-08-06 & Date =< 2014-08-30)
    summarise(mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The filter line is not working for me and I can't figure out how to filter by dates using this method. I would like to get the mean for each month without having to calculate it one by one - and ideally extract the monthly means into a new dataframe or column that looks like...

```
Month         Average
Jan 2014         x
Feb 2014         y
...
Nov 2015         z
Dec 2015         a
```

I hope this makes sense. I can't find anything on stackoverflow that works with dates, attempting to do something similar to this (unless I am searching for the wrong functions). Many thanks!

Comment: If you don't put the quotes around the date elements `"2014-08-06"`

Comment: Maybe you want `aggregate(dat$Price, list(ym=format(dat$Date, "%Y-%m")), mean)`. Note that the variable ym is a character variable as R does not have a storage mechanism for year-month combinations. Also note that for this to order properly you need to use year-month, rather than month-year or you'd have to reset the order afterward.

Comment: I have tried that but it comes up with error messages! @akrun

Comment: @JayJ when working with Date variables, it is especially helpful to provide your example data using `dput`. This allows us to cut and paste the data, and also helps us diagnose some potential issues that are common in such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using all dplyr functions, with help from @user108636

```
df %>%
    select(Date, Price) %>%
    arrange(Date) %>%
    mutate(Month_Year = substr(Date, 1,7)) %>%
    group_by(Month_Year) %>%
    summarise(mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The select function selects the date and price columns.
The arrange function arranges my dataframe according to the date - with the earliest date first. The mutate function adds another column which excludes the day and leaves us with, for example...

```
Month_Year
2015-10
2015-10
2015-11
2015-12
2015-12
```

The group by function groups all the months together and the summarise function calculates the mean of the price of each month.

Answer (score 3):

I made a separate column in your data set that contains only year and month. Then, I did a `group_by` on that column to get the means for each month.

```
Date <- c("2014-08-06", "2014-08-06", "2014-09-15", "2014-06-04", "2015-01-19", "2015-05-23", "2014-07-21")
Price <- c(22,89,56,41,11,5,108)

Date <- as.Date(Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

df <- data.frame(Date, Price)
df$Month_Year <- substr(df$Date, 1,7)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #select(Date, Price) %>%
  group_by(Month_Year) %>%
  summarise(mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but I keep getting 'error: unknown column 'Month_Year' .... But when I check the structure it's all there! No idea why I am getting this error message @user108363

Comment: @JayJ does your select statement contain Month_Year?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

# in case  Date is of type character
setDT(df1)[, .(Average = mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE)), keyby = .(Yr.Mon = substr(Date, 1,7))]

# in case Date is of class Date or POSIXct
setDT(df2)[, .(Average = mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE)), keyby = .(Yr.Mon = format(Date, "%Y-%m"))]
```

> ```
>     Yr.Mon Average
> 1: 2014-06    41.0
> 2: 2014-07   108.0
> 3: 2014-08    55.5
> 4: 2014-09    56.0
> 5: 2015-01    11.0
> 6: 2015-05     5.0
> ```

Note that the grouping variable `Yr.Mon` is created "on-the-fly" in the `keyby` clause.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread(
  "Date          Price
2014-08-06       22
2014-08-06       89
2014-09-15       56
2014-06-04       41
2015-01-19       11
2015-05-23        5
2014-07-21      108")
df2 <- df1[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should mean your price data by month-year.

```
library(zoo)

#Pull out columns
Price<-df1["Price"]
Date<-df1["Date"]

#Put in Zoo
zooPrice <- zoo(Price,Date)

#Monthly mean with year (vector)
monthly.avg <- apply.monthly(zooPrice, mean)

#function to change back to DF
zooToDf <- function(z) {
    df <- as.data.frame(z) 
    df$Date <- time(z) #create a Date column
    rownames(df) <- NULL #so row names not filled with dates
    df <- df[,c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))] #reorder columns so Date first
    return(df)
}

#Apply function to create new Df with data!
MonthYearAvg<-zooToDf(monthly.avg)
```

Comment: Although this is a nice base R answer, please, note that it only aggregates by *Month* but not by *Year-Month* as requested. Thus, January 2014 and January 2015 are combined..

Comment: Oh, the consise base R solution is gone now. What a pitty.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your column to a `Date` object and use `format`

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2014-08-06", "2014-08-06", "2014-09-15", "2014-06-04", "2015-01-19", "2015-05-23", "2014-07-21"), 
  Price = c(22, 89, 56, 41, 11, 5, 108))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Month_Year = as.Date(Date) %>% format("%b %Y")) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Month_Year   avg
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 août 2014   55.5
2 janv. 2015  11  
3 juil. 2014 108  
4 juin 2014   41  
5 mai 2015     5  
6 sept. 2014  56
```